# how to auto populate form_form tag fields in rails in edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, edit

i understand that if someone goes to an objects edit path, the form_for fields should populate. most of mines do except this one field, which has a has_many :through relationship with another table. how do you get it to pre populate with whatever the using typed in at creation?

for example...

```
        <div class="lesson_content">
            <%= f.label :content %>
            <%= f.text_area :content %>
        </div>

        <div class="tags">
            <%= f.label :tag_names, "Tags" %>
            <%= f.text_field :tag_names, data: { autocomplete_source: tags_path} %>
        </div>
```

my lesson content will populate correctly, but not my tags field. i have a lessons table, tags table, and an intervening tags_relationship table.

my lessons class is...

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :desc, :content, :tag_names
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :tag_relationships, :autosave => true 
  has_many :tags, :through => :tag_relationships, :autosave => true
```

how do i get the tags field to populate? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is call `accepts_nested_attributes_for` from your Lesson class:

```
# app/models/lesson.rb
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :desc, :content, :tag_names
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :tag_relationships, :autosave => true 
  has_many :tags, :through => :tag_relationships, :autosave => true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
end
```

And then, in your controller/view:

```
# app/controllers/lessons_controller.rb
class LessonsController < ActiveSupport::Controller
  def edit
    @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
  end
end

<%= form_for(@lesson) do |f| %>
  <div class="lesson_content">
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="tags">
    <%- @lesson.tags.each do |tag| -%>
      <%= fields_for(tag) do |t| %>
        <%= t.label :name, "Tag" %>
        <%= t.text_field :name, data: { autocomplete_source: tags_path} %>
      <%- end -%>
    <%- end -%>
  </div>
<%- end -%>
```

However, this would show a text field for every tag. If you want to use a single text field for all the tags (separated by commas, for example), and also retrieve lessons filtering by tags, you should check this gem: [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on).

Answer (score 2):

What you need is fields_for nested in your form.  Details are here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Even better, check out this great screencast from Ryan Bates that he just released http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised